# Custom back button for image picker when photo library selected

Tags: ios, swift3, uinavigationcontroller, uiimagepickercontroller, back-button

I am **presenting** an `UIImagePickerController` and, when it is set to type `photoLibrary`, I am showing a custom back button in the navigation bar when user has first selected an album and then the image picker navigates to a new view to show the photos there:

```
let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: image, style: .plain, target: self, action: #selector(navigateBack))
viewController.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Then I have:

```
func navigateBack() {
    self.navigationController.popViewController(animated: true)
}
```

That method is called when I run the app and I tap my custom back button, but nothing happens, I don't navigate back from the photo selection screen to the previous album selection one.

Comment: Are you expecting the default photo library navigations with your custom one?